# angularjs calculate time difference between start time and current time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, difference, stopwatch

I'm trying to create something similar to a stop watch in an AngularJS app.

I've got a 'start' button that when clicked, the app will set a startTime variable which gets the current time and then I want another variable which updates every second and calculates the difference in seconds between the startTime variable and the current time which I can use as the stop watch value that's displayed to the user.
I'll also need to be able to stop and restart the timer so I'd like the stop watch value to be stored in seconds so that I can easily start the timer at any number of seconds and resume the timer.

What's the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: If you just want the seconds between two `Date` objects (now and `startTime`), try `var sec = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000`

Comment: This is basically what I want but I need the difference to be dynamically updated every second so that the current difference can be displayed in real time, rather than just calculating the difference between two Date objects once.

Comment: So run that in an `$interval` with delay of `1000`. `new Date()` will always be the current time and presumably, `startTime` doesn't change.

Comment: Oops of course! Don't know why I didn't think of that already. Thanks :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comments above, something like this...

```
var startTime = new Date();
$scope.stopwatch = 0;

$interval(function() {
    $scope.stopwatch = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
}, 1000);
```

and in your template

```
<p>Seconds: {{ stopwatch }}</p>
```

Bonus points for creating a filter for formatting the seconds in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this, is by using $interval like so:

```
var stop, seconds=0;
stop = $interval(updatingFunc, 1000);
function updatingFunc(){
    seconds++;
    console.log(seconds);
    if(seconds === 4){ // Here you set whatever condition to cancel the interval
        $interval.stop(stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm doing something similar to this at the moment using the $timeout service. I really need the timer to be calculated and updated off of an actual point in time though (ie. a Date object) as I've been having issues with the timer getting out of sync when running on an iOS device if the app is being run in the background as it stops updating the timer.